# echo not found if result is empty

Tags: php, echo

Hello I have this code that scrapes a page inputed by the user, I want it to echo 'not found' if the user inputed a page number that isn't available like "1000000" how can i do that?

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  print "<br><br><br>";
  echo "<center>";
  print "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">";
  print "<input name=\"dgt\" id=\"hax\" style=\"width:400px\" type=\"text\">   ";
  print "<input name=\"submit\" value=\"Decrypt Hash\" type=\"submit\">";
  print "</form>";
} else {
  $string = file_get_contents('http://www.md5this.com/list.php?page='.$_POST['dgt']);

  $regex_pattern = "/<tr>([^`]*?)<\/tr>/";

  unset($matches);
  preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $string, $matches);


  foreach ($matches[0] as $paragraph) {
    echo $paragraph;
    echo "<br>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then do a check to see if `$matches[0]` is empty. If not, run through the `$matches[0]`. If it is empty, then echo `Not found.` That is the most practical & realistic way to handle the data you are dealing with since ultimately you have no idea what an invalid page would be since the other site is out of your control.

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  print "<br><br><br>";
  echo "<center>";
  print "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">";
  print "<input name=\"dgt\" id=\"hax\" style=\"width:400px\" type=\"text\">   ";
  print "<input name=\"submit\" value=\"Decrypt Hash\" type=\"submit\">";
  print "</form>";
}
else {
  $string = file_get_contents('http://www.md5this.com/list.php?page=' . $_POST['dgt']);

  $regex_pattern = "/<tr>([^`]*?)<\/tr>/";

  unset($matches);
  preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $string, $matches);

  if(!empty($matches) && !empty($matches[0])) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $paragraph) {
      echo $paragraph;
      echo "<br>";
    }
  }
  else {
    echo 'Not found.';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this should work

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     print "<br><br><br>";
     echo "<center>";
     print "<form action=\"\" method=\"POST\">";
     print "<input name=\"dgt\" id=\"hax\" style=\"width:400px\" type=\"text\">   ";
     print "<input name=\"submit\" value=\"Decrypt Hash\" type=\"submit\">";
     print "</form>";
} else {


    if($_POST['dgt'] < 1000000){

      $string = file_get_contents('http://www.md5this.com/list.php?page='.$_POST['dgt']);

      $regex_pattern = "/<tr>([^`]*?)<\/tr>/";

      unset($matches);
      preg_match_all($regex_pattern, $string, $matches);

      foreach ($matches[0] as $paragraph) {
        echo $paragraph;
        echo "<br>";
      }


    }else{

            echo "Not Found";
    }


}
```